# Show specific news feed in Facebook Canvas Application

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

I develop Facebook canvas application and have the following question:
I succeeded getting the news feed of the user as json object.
Now I want to show inside the Canvas some of the news feed, for example only the post that include specific words.
I want them to look like in original Facebook news feed.
I develop my application with java.
How I can do this?